# Half or 1/4 spin and return two circles

Tags: css, css-animations

I have never done animations in CSS, what I'm trying to get is something like cog's animations two circles spinning, one to the right and the other to the left without overlapping...
I think I got the animation(sort of) but not the drawing I think..
I have this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Tankers/8dxh94zp/9/
the "figures" are correct and the location also correct but the animation is not.
when they spin it overlaps may be is because the object are not 100% squares?, what need to be visible is just half circles just the way that is in my demo..
HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bott"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes half_spin {
        0% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        40% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
                transform: rotate(20deg);
        }
        60% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        80% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                transform: rotate(-20deg);
        }
        100% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.top {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 151px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 151px;
  position: relative;
  animation: half_spin 5000ms ease-in-out infinite;
}
.top:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bott {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 151px;
  border-top-right-radius: 151px;
  animation: half_spin 5000ms ease-in-out infinite reverse;
  position: relative;
}
.bott:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  content: " ";
  bottom: 0;
  left :0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code snippet is what you're looking for. I added a `transform-origin` property to both the top and bottom half-circles to specify the point that we're rotating around.

Both divs should rotate around the midpoint of their flat edge, for the top that is `transform-origin: 50% 0%;` and for the bottom it is `transform-origin: 50% 100%;`

```css
@keyframes half_spin {
        0% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        40% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
                transform: rotate(20deg);
        }
        60% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        80% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
                transform: rotate(-20deg);
        }
        100% {
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
                transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.top {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 151px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 151px;
  position: relative;
  animation: half_spin 5000ms ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.top:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bott {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 151px;
  border-top-right-radius: 151px;
  animation: half_spin 5000ms ease-in-out infinite;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.bott:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  content: " ";
  bottom: 0;
  left :0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="top">

</div>
<div class="bott">

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: So, transform-origin is use to indicate the "center" or the point of origin from where the animation should start which in any case is the center of any object, I'm assuming that transform-origin has some params as transform-origin: Y X Z; axis as in top, bottom, left right and DOF, or this is just 2D?...
in any case, thank you very much.

Comment: @Tanker that is correct! You can specify a z-offset as well. The [MDN web docs for transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) can probably explain the different syntax options better than I can.